# Using AWS CodeBuild environment variable inside buildspec session

Tags: variables, buildspec

I created an environment variable in AWS CodeBuild.

How can I use it inside buildspec session ?

Answer (score 0):

It was very simple.
After creating any environment variable, on buildspec we can use $variable_name for calling it.

I realized that my real problem was that the variable to be lowercase.
So i used ${variable_name,,} to convert it